# After pushing to an array from an ajax call, getting array element by index shows undefined, but console show array content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call when my page loads, the result is a integer number that I need to save in a variable to use later with other jquery functions.

This is my code right now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ajaxResult = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Po_general/obtenerIdConsecutivo',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (returned) {
            var returned = JSON.parse(returned);
            var idPog = returned.idPog;
            ajaxResult.push(idPog);
        }
    });
    //This shows me the array in the console
    console.log(ajaxResult);
    //This shows undefined
    console.log(ajaxResult[0]);
    /*
     * Additional jquery functions
     */
});
```

console.log(ajaxResult) shows me the array in the console

```
[]
   0: 2
   length: 1
```

But when I want to access ajaxResult[0] it shows as undefined.

Comment: Do your `console.log` call inside the `success` function.

Comment: @J.Titus It works when I do that inside the success function, but I need to use that value outside the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ajaxResult = [];
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Po_general/obtenerIdConsecutivo',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (returned) {
        var returned = JSON.parse(returned);
        var idPog = returned.idPog;
        ajaxResult.push(idPog);
    }
});
//This shows me the array in the console
console.log(ajaxResult);
//This shows undefined
console.log(ajaxResult[0]);
/*
 * Additional jquery functions
 */
```

});